# Unsupported operand types error when creating new Webform handler

Tags: 8, webforms

Following the example here: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/webform/webform-cookbook/how-to-programmatically-add-a-handler-to-a-new-webform

I've created my handler manager sucessfully, however, when I go to create the handler, I get the error

> Error: Unsupported operand types in Drupal\webform\Plugin\WebformHandlerBase->setConfiguration() (line 363 of /var/www/sitename/web/modules/contrib/webform/src/Plugin/WebformHandlerBase.php

Here's a sample of the code I'm using to get this error

```
$webform_machine_name = 'form_id';
$webform = \Drupal\webform\Entity\Webform::load($webform_machine_name);

$handler_manager = \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.webform.handler');

// Create webform handler.
$handler_configuration = [
  'id' => 'my_form_handler',
  'label' => 'My form handler',
  'handler_id' => 'my_form_handler',
  'status' => 1,
  'weight' => 0,
  'settings' => [],
];

$handler = $handler_manager->createInstance('my_form_handler', $handler_configuration );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I look at [line 263 in \Drupal\webform\Plugin\WebformHandlerBase](https://cgit.drupalcode.org/webform/tree/src/Plugin/WebformHandlerBase.php#n351) there is the below code...

```
$this->configuration = $configuration['settings'] + $this->defaultConfiguration();
```

Your `Unsupported operand types` error message indicates that one of those variables/properties is not an array.

My best guess is that `\Drupal\webform\Plugin\WebformHandlerBase::defaultConfiguration` is not returning an `array()` because your `$configuration['settings']` is set to an empty array.

Comment: Thanks for this. I discovered that I had commented out the contents of the defaultConfiguration method, so it was returning null. Oops.